# Automatically generate implementations of base class methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a shortcut of some kind in C# (VS 2008) to automatically implement the virtual and abstract base class methods in a derived class?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For virtual methods, you can type `override` and then a space. Intellisense should offer you a list of options.

For abstract methods and properties, you can use the smart tag on the base class or interface (also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> will show the smart tag menu) to generate the concrete items.

For example, in the following code snippet, you could place the caret at the end of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to then select Implement Interface, and the `PropertyChanged` event would be added to `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```

Comment: This works well for Interface implementations. I want to derive a class from another class and there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: @Kangkan: If the other class has abstract methods, it works the same way as with interfaces. however, if it has virtual methods with implementations, you should only override the ones you need to. I'm not sure what "easy way" you're missing, but just type override and a space as above and it will give you a lsit of the methods available. You shouldn't need to override them all.

Comment: I want to add additional properties and methods to my class while maintaining all the methods and attributes from the base class. So I shall like to get the methods and properties implemented as base.method() way.

Comment: @Kangkan: When you derive from a class, you inherit all its methods and properties. You only need to override the ones where you want to modify their behaviour. What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: So. Much. Time. Saved. :-D

Comment: "Ctrl + ." option Worked for me. Thanks for saving lot time.

Answer (score 21):

Just type the Interface that you want to implement, and then click on the Smart Tag, a context menu will popup, and then you can select either Implement Interface or Implement Interface Explicitly:

> [image]

All the members to be overridden will be contained within a code region that is named to reflect its purpose.

All the members will have a line that throws a `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: The OP talks about deriving class from base class and not about implementing interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

For virtual methods type **override**, give an space and intellisense will show you all methods that can be inherited.

Answer (score 3):

As the others have mentioned, the smart tag (via `Ctrl+.` and `Alt+Shft+F10`) will solve your problem, however Visual Studio has an annoying option that will automatically wrap the generated properties/methods with a region like this:

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged members
...
#endregion
```

You can turn this functionality by going to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced`. There is a checkbox called `Implement Interface > Surround generated code with #region`. Just make sure it is unchecked.

Comment: I think the region is kind of nice as it flags the methods as related to the interface, and also makes the whole group collapsible.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think this existed when the original question was asked, but at least as of VS 2013, you can automatically create stubs for abstract methods & properties.  Just right click on the abstract class name (in your class definition) and pick "Implement Abstract Class".  Just like CMS showed with automatically implementing interfaces.

Comment: CMS clicked the "Smart Tag", the tiny box that appears under the M in `MyInterface` in his picture.

Answer (score 1):

The current official Microsoft documentation for automatically implementing an abstract base class is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/implement-abstract-class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want all inheriting/implementing classes to implement a new defined abstract method.

1. Go to one of the inheriting/implementing classes
2. use smart tag menu <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
3. implement abstract class / interface
4. watch for options at the bottom of the popup window "Project" or "Solution"
   [image: Smart tag Menu Pop Up]